# connectedness of conjugacy classes of a fixed matrix $A$ but with the first column invariant

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology, connectedness

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb C)$ be a fixed matrix. The set $\{S^{-1} A S: S \in GL_n(\mathbb C)\}$ is a continuous image of $GL_n(\mathbb C)$, so I think it should be a connected set. Let $A = (a_1, \dots, a_n)$ where $a_j \in \mathbb C^n$ denotes the columns of $A$. Let $F = \{S^{-1} A S: S \in GL_n(\mathbb C) \text{ and } (S^{-1}AS)_{\cdot,1} = a_1\}$. Is the set $F$ still connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition $(S^{-1}AS)_{\cdot,1} = a_1$ is equivalent to $(SA-AS)e_1 = 0$.
Let $S$ be a matrix in your set and let $\gamma : [0,1]\to\mathbb C$ be a path such that $\gamma(0) = 0$, $\gamma(1) = 1$, and $\det(S + \gamma(t)(I-S))\neq 0$. It is now easy to see that $S(t) = S + \gamma(t)(I-S)$ is in your set for each $t\in [0,1]$ with $S(0) = S$ and $S(1) = I$. So, we have found a path within your set from $S$ to $I$. This shows that it is connected.

Comment: May I ask why $\gamma(t)$ exists such that $\det(S + \gamma(t)(I-S)) \neq 0$?

Comment: @iris2017 Sure, you may. Let $Z$ be the set of all $z\in\mathbb C$ such that $-z/(1-z)$ is an eigenvalue of $S$. Obviously, the set $Z$ is a finite set. Now, choose $\gamma : [0,1]\to\mathbb C$ continuous such that $\gamma(0) = 0$, $\gamma(1) = 1$ and $\gamma(t)\notin Z$ for each $t\in [0,1]$. This is obviously possible. Then$$S + \gamma(t)(I-S) = (1-\gamma(t))S + \gamma(t)I = (1-\gamma(t))\left(S + \frac{\gamma(t)}{1-\gamma(t)}I\right),$$is invertible for any $t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer.

Comment: Could you comment on the case if we replace the filed $\mathbb C$ by $\mathbb R$? Thanks.

Comment: $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ is not connected.

Comment: Yes. The conjugacy class $\{S^{-1}AS\}$ will have at most two connected components. I am interested in whether there will be at most two connected components if we put the restriction.

Comment: I tried to follow your construction. But when we are in $\mathbb R$, it is not clear we can define the path $\gamma$ such that the determinant is nonvanishing.